# div inside td is resetting the width of td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have few circle divs,

```
.green-circle {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    /*margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;*/
    /*margin-top: 10px;*/
}
```

Which is getting applied to table > td , during run time.

Now the problem is it's resetting the td width and the next td kind of overlaps with current one.But I want to keep the td width intact irrespective of div applied (circle)

```css
.green-circle {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    /*margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;*/
    /*margin-top: 10px;*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table id="tblRandomSummary" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-condensed responsive no-footer dtr-inline dataTable collapsed" role="grid" aria-describedby="tblRandomSummary_info" style="width: 1029px;">
 <thead>
 <tr role="row">
  <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 47px;" aria-label="Circuit: activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending">Circuit</th>
  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 71px;" aria-label="WashType: activate to sort column ascending">WashType</th>
  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 115px;" aria-label="AverageDuration: activate to sort column ascending">AverageDuration</th>
  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 71px;" aria-label="FirstRinse: activate to sort column ascending">FirstRinse</th>
  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 143px;" aria-label="CausticRecirculation: activate to sort column ascending">CausticRecirculation</th>
  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 125px;" aria-label="IntermediateRinse: activate to sort column ascending">IntermediateRinse</th>
  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 123px;" aria-label="AcidRecirculation: activate to sort column ascending">AcidRecirculation</th>
  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 126px;" aria-label="IntermediateRinse: activate to sort column ascending">IntermediateRinse</th>
  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="HeatSterilizeNoPulsing: activate to sort column ascending">HeatSterilizeNoPulsing</th>
  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="HeatSterilizePulsing: activate to sort column ascending">HeatSterilizePulsing</th>
  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="SecondSemiAutoRecirculation: activate to sort column ascending">SecondSemiAutoRecirculation</th>
  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="SanitiserRecirculation: activate to sort column ascending">SanitiserRecirculation</th>
  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="FinalRinse: activate to sort column ascending">FinalRinse</th>
  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="Idle: activate to sort column ascending">Idle</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr role="row" class="odd">
  <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
  <td>Acid</td>
  <td>3.75 mins</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td class="green-circle">0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td style="display: none;">0</td>
  <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
  <td style="display: none;">0</td>
  <td style="display: none;">0</td>
  <td style="display: none;"></td>
  <td style="display: none;">0</td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
  <td>SemiAuto</td>
  <td>3.75 mins</td>
  <td class="green-circle">0</td>
  <td class="green-circle">0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td style="display: none;">0</td>
  <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
  <td style="display: none;">0</td>
  <td style="display: none;">0</td>
  <td style="display: none;"></td>
  <td style="display: none;">0</td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
  <td>SemiAuto &amp; Acid</td>
  <td>3.75 mins</td>
  <td class="green-circle">0</td>
  <td class="green-circle">0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td style="display: none;">0</td>
  <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
  <td style="display: none;">0</td>
  <td style="display: none;">0</td>
  <td style="display: none;"></td>
  <td style="display: none;">0</td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
  <td>No Wash</td>
  <td>4.13 mins</td>
  <td class="green-circle">0</td>
  <td class="green-circle">0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td style="display: none;">0</td>
  <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
  <td style="display: none;">0</td>
  <td style="display: none;">0</td>
  <td style="display: none;"></td>
  <td style="display: none;">0</td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
  <td>Rinse</td>
  <td>4.44 mins</td>
  <td class="green-circle">0</td>
  <td class="green-circle">0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td style="display: none;">0</td>
  <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
  <td style="display: none;">0</td>
  <td style="display: none;">0</td>
  <td style="display: none;"></td>
  <td style="display: none;">0</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I suggest you to use a `span` with class name `green-circle` or you can use a pseudo element to have the samy styles. In that way, you can solve this issue. This issue is happening because, the td has display property `table-cell` and when you override it with `inline-block`, the issue is happening.

Comment: @Pedram thanks for the edit.

Comment: I would suggest to start by placing the "green-circle" class as it's own element inside the td instead of styling the circle in the td itself

Comment: By styling the td you resize it to `width: 20px;`. As others said, it's better to add an element (the green-circle) inside the td.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the `:before` pseudo element for the circle and use `position: absolute` for the circle position adjustment.

```css
.green-circle {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.green-circle:before {
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 7px;
  top: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table id="tblRandomSummary" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-condensed responsive no-footer dtr-inline dataTable collapsed" role="grid" aria-describedby="tblRandomSummary_info" style="width: 1029px;">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 47px;" aria-label="Circuit: activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending">Circuit</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 71px;" aria-label="WashType: activate to sort column ascending">WashType</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 115px;" aria-label="AverageDuration: activate to sort column ascending">AverageDuration</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 71px;" aria-label="FirstRinse: activate to sort column ascending">FirstRinse</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 143px;" aria-label="CausticRecirculation: activate to sort column ascending">CausticRecirculation</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 125px;" aria-label="IntermediateRinse: activate to sort column ascending">IntermediateRinse</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 123px;" aria-label="AcidRecirculation: activate to sort column ascending">AcidRecirculation</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 126px;" aria-label="IntermediateRinse: activate to sort column ascending">IntermediateRinse</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="HeatSterilizeNoPulsing: activate to sort column ascending">HeatSterilizeNoPulsing</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="HeatSterilizePulsing: activate to sort column ascending">HeatSterilizePulsing</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="SecondSemiAutoRecirculation: activate to sort column ascending">SecondSemiAutoRecirculation</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="SanitiserRecirculation: activate to sort column ascending">SanitiserRecirculation</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="FinalRinse: activate to sort column ascending">FinalRinse</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="Idle: activate to sort column ascending">Idle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
      <td>Acid</td>
      <td>3.75 mins</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
      <td>SemiAuto</td>
      <td>3.75 mins</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
      <td>SemiAuto &amp; Acid</td>
      <td>3.75 mins</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
      <td>No Wash</td>
      <td>4.13 mins</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
      <td>Rinse</td>
      <td>4.44 mins</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: For some reason , the new answer is not working , I know it's working in snippet though. Any thoughts!

Comment: @Simsons what issue you are facing...?

Comment: Green circle it self is not appearing , debugging if anything else is over riding it...

Comment: Can I I remove or hide the number , just want the shape.

Comment: @Simsons you can hide it by applying the same color as background or just remove it

Answer (score 2):

Keep your circle class on a div inside td

```css
.green-circle {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;*/
  /*margin-top: 10px;*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table id="tblRandomSummary" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-condensed responsive no-footer dtr-inline dataTable collapsed" role="grid" aria-describedby="tblRandomSummary_info" style="width: 1029px;">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 47px;" aria-label="Circuit: activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending">Circuit</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 71px;" aria-label="WashType: activate to sort column ascending">WashType</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 115px;" aria-label="AverageDuration: activate to sort column ascending">AverageDuration</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 71px;" aria-label="FirstRinse: activate to sort column ascending">FirstRinse</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 143px;" aria-label="CausticRecirculation: activate to sort column ascending">CausticRecirculation</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 125px;" aria-label="IntermediateRinse: activate to sort column ascending">IntermediateRinse</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 123px;" aria-label="AcidRecirculation: activate to sort column ascending">AcidRecirculation</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 126px;" aria-label="IntermediateRinse: activate to sort column ascending">IntermediateRinse</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="HeatSterilizeNoPulsing: activate to sort column ascending">HeatSterilizeNoPulsing</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="HeatSterilizePulsing: activate to sort column ascending">HeatSterilizePulsing</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="SecondSemiAutoRecirculation: activate to sort column ascending">SecondSemiAutoRecirculation</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="SanitiserRecirculation: activate to sort column ascending">SanitiserRecirculation</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="FinalRinse: activate to sort column ascending">FinalRinse</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="Idle: activate to sort column ascending">Idle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
      <td>Acid</td>
      <td>3.75 mins</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><div class="green-circle">0</div></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
      <td>SemiAuto</td>
      <td>3.75 mins</td>
      <td><div class="green-circle">0</div></td>
      <td><div class="green-circle">0</div></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
      <td>SemiAuto &amp; Acid</td>
      <td>3.75 mins</td>
      <td><div class="green-circle">0</div></td>
      <td><div class="green-circle">0</div></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
      <td>No Wash</td>
      <td>4.13 mins</td>
      <td><div class="green-circle">0</div></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
      <td>Rinse</td>
      <td>4.44 mins</td>
      <td><div class="green-circle">0</div></td>
      <td><div class="green-circle">0</div></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, The table is generated dynamically with jQuery dataTable,https://datatables.net, So cant append div in td.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of altering `td` `width` you can use `:before` pseudo element.

**Here is an working example**

```css
.green-circle {
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
}
.green-circle:before {
  content: '';
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  top: 14px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table id="tblRandomSummary" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-condensed responsive no-footer dtr-inline dataTable collapsed" role="grid" aria-describedby="tblRandomSummary_info" style="width: 1029px;">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 47px;" aria-label="Circuit: activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending">Circuit</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 71px;" aria-label="WashType: activate to sort column ascending">WashType</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 115px;" aria-label="AverageDuration: activate to sort column ascending">AverageDuration</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 71px;" aria-label="FirstRinse: activate to sort column ascending">FirstRinse</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 143px;" aria-label="CausticRecirculation: activate to sort column ascending">CausticRecirculation</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 125px;" aria-label="IntermediateRinse: activate to sort column ascending">IntermediateRinse</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 123px;" aria-label="AcidRecirculation: activate to sort column ascending">AcidRecirculation</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 126px;" aria-label="IntermediateRinse: activate to sort column ascending">IntermediateRinse</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="HeatSterilizeNoPulsing: activate to sort column ascending">HeatSterilizeNoPulsing</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="HeatSterilizePulsing: activate to sort column ascending">HeatSterilizePulsing</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="SecondSemiAutoRecirculation: activate to sort column ascending">SecondSemiAutoRecirculation</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="SanitiserRecirculation: activate to sort column ascending">SanitiserRecirculation</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="FinalRinse: activate to sort column ascending">FinalRinse</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="Idle: activate to sort column ascending">Idle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
      <td>Acid</td>
      <td>3.75 mins</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
      <td>SemiAuto</td>
      <td>3.75 mins</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
      <td>SemiAuto &amp; Acid</td>
      <td>3.75 mins</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
      <td>No Wash</td>
      <td>4.13 mins</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
      <td>Rinse</td>
      <td>4.44 mins</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

@Simsons - check if it works for you and if it does remove `!important` from css. If then it does not it means that some other styles are overwriting your styles. My quess is, that `position` is overwritten.

```css
.green-circle {
  position: relative!important;
  color: #FFF;
}
.green-circle:before {
  content: '';
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block!important;
  position: absolute!important;
  left: 6px!important;
  top: 14px!important;
  z-index: -1!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table id="tblRandomSummary" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-condensed responsive no-footer dtr-inline dataTable collapsed" role="grid" aria-describedby="tblRandomSummary_info" style="width: 1029px;">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 47px;" aria-label="Circuit: activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending">Circuit</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 71px;" aria-label="WashType: activate to sort column ascending">WashType</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 115px;" aria-label="AverageDuration: activate to sort column ascending">AverageDuration</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 71px;" aria-label="FirstRinse: activate to sort column ascending">FirstRinse</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 143px;" aria-label="CausticRecirculation: activate to sort column ascending">CausticRecirculation</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 125px;" aria-label="IntermediateRinse: activate to sort column ascending">IntermediateRinse</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 123px;" aria-label="AcidRecirculation: activate to sort column ascending">AcidRecirculation</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 126px;" aria-label="IntermediateRinse: activate to sort column ascending">IntermediateRinse</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="HeatSterilizeNoPulsing: activate to sort column ascending">HeatSterilizeNoPulsing</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="HeatSterilizePulsing: activate to sort column ascending">HeatSterilizePulsing</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="SecondSemiAutoRecirculation: activate to sort column ascending">SecondSemiAutoRecirculation</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="SanitiserRecirculation: activate to sort column ascending">SanitiserRecirculation</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="FinalRinse: activate to sort column ascending">FinalRinse</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblRandomSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="Idle: activate to sort column ascending">Idle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
      <td>Acid</td>
      <td>3.75 mins</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
      <td>SemiAuto</td>
      <td>3.75 mins</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
      <td>SemiAuto &amp; Acid</td>
      <td>3.75 mins</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
      <td>No Wash</td>
      <td>4.13 mins</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Engine001</td>
      <td>Rinse</td>
      <td>4.44 mins</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td class="green-circle">0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td class="red-circle" style="display: none;">4</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, This snippet is not adding the green circles.

Comment: @Simsons what browser are you using? I tested it on chrome, firefox, edge and ie and it works properly.